# Isomorphic group to the multiplicative group of a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

Suppose that I have an abelian group $G$ and an epimorphism from $G$ to $(K^*)\times (K^*), $ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field. Is it true that $G$ cannot be isomorpic to $K^*.$?

Comment: The squaring map from $K^*$ to $(K^*)^2$ is onto (since $K$ is algebraically closed), and is a group homomorphism since $K^*$ is abelian. So you could take $G=K^*$ and get an epimorphism from $G$ to $(K^*)^2$.

Comment: So your question is "for $K$ an algebraically closed field, can there be an epimorphism $K^*\to(K^*)^2$?". Right?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see that i was not clear. By $(K^*)^2$ i meant $K^∗\times K^∗$.

Comment: @DaanMichiels, yeah, i want to know if there exists an epimorphism $K^*\to K^*\times K^*,$ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field and $K^*=K\setminus\{ 0\}.$

Comment: @Hector: Then **please** edit the question and write it correctly. $(K^*)^2$, in the context of fields, is naturally interpreted to be $\{a^2\mid a\in K^*\}$. If you meant $K^*\times K^*$, then you need to write it as such.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^*$ is isomorphic to the product of additive groups $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$, the first component being the argument over $2 \pi$ and the second being the log of the modulus. As additive groups, $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, since they're both continuum-dimensional rational vector spaces. There's clearly an epimorphism from $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R})\times(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R})$, and hence an epimorphism from $\mathbb{C}^*$ to $\mathbb{C}^* \times \mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Ok  everything is correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Hector:  Please accept the answer to show that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: @TaraB, i am not sure how to do that. Sorry i am new here.

Comment: @Hector: You have done it. It is the green tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Hector:  Yes, you've done it now.  You hadn't yet when I wrote my comment.